# What header file to include to use ESP return code macro constants?

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, esp8266wifi

It is ESP8266, and I am using the Arduino framework (VS Code + Platform IO). [The documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/network/esp_now.html) uses constants like `ESP_OK` or `ESP_ERR_ESPNOW_INTERNAL`, but what to include to use them with the Arduino framework? There seems to be no "esp_now.h" but only "espnow.h" (.platformio\packages\framework-arduinoespressif8266\tools\sdk\include\espnow.h), and it does not include such constants.

Comment: That documentation is for ESP-IDF i.e. ESP32. Did you take a look at https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp-now-esp8266-nodemcu-arduino-ide/

Comment: try to download the files manually from github and adding to libs folder